# Is there a limit to the number of objects I can detect in TFLite?

Tags: tensorflow-lite

From Tensorflow's [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview),
I found that the model they provided had a maximum number of 10 objects per image. Could I make a model that could detect more objects in an image (like 16 for example)? or is it a software limitation by TFLite?

Could a model like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnntrewH0xg&t=42s) be implemented on device, without the use of the cloud?

Comment: Of course you can detect more or less objects. You have to train model with your own dataset following the instructions in tensorflow github for object detection

Answer (score 0):

Usually there's a limit to how many objects "survive" the non-max suppression stage. You can set this limit higher.

Often there is an upper limit to how many objects can be detected in total, but it depends on the size of the search grid and how many detectors there are per grid cell. For something like SSD that's usually in the 1000s or even 10,000s.